# Loading file using scikit-learn load_files

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I downloaded the [20 newsgroup tar file](http://qwone.com/~jason/20Newsgroups/) and extracted it. I pointed the `load_files` function to the train file, but I keep getting error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python\DataScience\t.py", line 14, in <module>
    data=load_files("\dataSet\20news-bydate\20news-bydate-train")
  File "C:\Users\Khoa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\datasets\base.py", line 166, in load_files
    folders = [f for f in sorted(listdir(container_path))
OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: '\\dataSet\x10news-bydate\x10news-bydate-train'
```

This is my code:

```
data=load_files("\dataSet\20news-bydate\20news-bydate-train")
```

Can you show me the correct code?

Answer (score 0):

It would seem to me you need to remove the preceding "\".

```
data = load_files('dataSet\2020news-bydate\20news-bydate-train')
```